# Recursively list files with file names, folder names and permission

Tags: files, permissions, find, ls

Is there anyway I can list files by typing a command in the shell which lists all the file names, folder names and their permissions in CentOS?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes for example, if I have the following structure: Folder A > File 1, File 2, Folder AA [File AA1, File AA2] etc, so I wish to list all folders and all files inside these folders along with their permissions in a text file. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [tree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), you may have to install it first. Per default tree does not show permissions, to show permissions next to the filename run

```
tree -p
```

which will recursively list all folders and directories within the current directory including permissions.

Answer (score 10):

`ls -lR` lists the contents of directories recursively. The output is hard to process automatically, but for manual browsing it may be good because it's what you're familiar with.

The `find` command lists files recursively. You can customize its output, for example the following command prints permissions like `ls -l` does before each file name:

```
find -printf '%M %p\n'
```

This output can be processed mechanically if there are no newlines in your file names. If you replace `\n` (newline) by `\000` (null byte), you can process the output with tools that support null-separated records.

Both `ls` and `find` only print traditional unix permissions, not access control lists. For a recursive listing of all file permissions including ACL information, run

```
getfacl -R .
```

The output can be processed mechanically (special characters are sorted); in particular, it can be fed to `setfacl --restore` to replicate the permissions to another tree with the same file names.

Answer (score 5):

You want `find` for this.

```
find some/dir -ls > output.txt
```

From the [`find` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> **`-ls`**
>
>   True; list current file in
>   **`ls -dils`**
>   format on standard output.

From the [`ls` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **`-l`**
>
>   use a long listing format

Answer (score 0):

The `stat` command executed by the `find` command will give you permissions and a whole lot more:

```bash
$ find . -exec stat {} +

  File: '.'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10306h/66310d   Inode: 1326677     Links: 3
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    rick)   Gid: ( 1000/    rick)
Access: 2020-06-24 17:00:52.131209006 -0600
Modify: 2020-06-13 09:21:40.489850096 -0600
Change: 2020-06-13 09:21:40.489850096 -0600
 Birth: -

  File: './.eyesome-sunset'
  Size: 8           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10306h/66310d   Inode: 1323438     Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-06-23 04:32:44.808321580 -0600
Modify: 2020-06-02 16:37:33.282346160 -0600
Change: 2020-06-02 16:37:33.282346160 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score -1):

`ls` is a command to list computer files in Unix 
`ls -l` list items in directory
`ls -R` recursively list file

```
ls -lR
```

Comment: This was in Gilles answer.  Also your explanation of `ls -l` doesn't explain what the `-l` is at all.